# Java Thread Pool Timing Issue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I'm trying to use a thread pool to execute some code, however I'm having some trouble getting it to run without errors.

Here is my current structure:

```
while (!(queue.IsEmpty())) 
{ 
    currentItem= queue.GetNextItem();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentItem.destinations.GetNoOfItems(); i++) //for each neighbor of currentItem
    {                    
         threadPool.submit(new NeighbourThread(currentItem, allVertices, routetype, pqOpen, i, endLocation));
    }
    //threadPool.shutdown();
}
```

NeighbourThread class:

```
public class NeighbourThread implements Runnable {
    Vertex tempVertex, endLocation;
    VertexHashMap allVertices;
    int routetype, i;
    PriorityQueue pqOpen;   

    public NeighbourThread(Vertex tempVertex, VertexHashMap allVertices, int routetype, PriorityQueue pqOpen, int i, Vertex endLocation)
    {
        ...variables
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
          ...execution code
          }
    }
```

My idea is that it will create the amount of threads required based on `currentItem.destinations.GetNoOfItems()`(as it reuses threads, I'm assuming if it reaches the limit on thread creation it will wait for a thread to finish execution and reuse it).

Once the threads have been allocated, it will submit each runnable to the thread and start it.

However I need my program to wait for all threads to finish execution before it loops back to the while loop.

After reading the documentation on .shutdown(), I think that stops any future use of the threadpool, which I'm guessing is why I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@3d4eac69 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@42a57993[Shutting down, pool size = 3, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 3]
```

I'm trying to improve execution time on my program and as I'm currently doing over 1.5 million invocations of what will be in the run() method, I feel this will help.

So is there anyway to get the program to wait until the threads have finished before continuing with the while loop?

Comment: Use FutureTask to know status of tasks, before shutdown. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/java-futuretask-example-program.html

Comment: Hint: what does `ExecutorService#submit()` return?

Comment: What's wrong with having a new instance of the `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @Nambari I'll have a look at that link now!

Comment: @MattBall it returns null if its completed - so I could store that and if its null I can continue to the while loop?

Comment: @M.Shaw I was told that creating a new ExecutorService is very resource heavy? Plus, as i'm using the output from for loop I can't move back to the while loop before all threads have finished executing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use the `Future`s to notify you when they have completed. Unfortunately, Java does not support *listenable* `Future`s out of the box, but you can use the Guava library to supplement you here.

Guava adds the `ListeneableFuture`, which you can make using the `Futures` utility class:

```
ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(threadPool);
// Collect the futures as you add them to the threadpool
List<ListenableFuture<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

while (! queue.IsEmpty()) 
{ 
    currentItem = queue.GetNextItem();

    for (int i = 0; i < currentItem.destinations.GetNoOfItems(); i++)
    {
        // NeighbourThread should be a Runnable and not a Thread!
        futures.add(executor.submit(new NeighbourThread(currentItem, allVertices, routetype, pqOpen, i, endLocation)));
    }
}

// Get notified when they're all done (doesn't imply success!)
Futures.allAsList(futures)).addListener(new Runnable() {

    // When this callback is executed, then everything has finished

}, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
```

Alternatively, you could do this with a `CountdownLatch` *if you know how many items you need to run upfront*.